# Best way to evolve library with method returning enum type as response

Tags: .net, design-patterns, architecture

I have a .NET library i have to evolve.

It has some methods that are returning enum as response .
For example:

```
    //v1.0
    public enum Vehicle
    {
        Truck,
        Mini,
        Superbike
    }

    public Vehicle getCar(){
        ...
        return Vehicle.XXX;
    }
```

In version 2.0 I want to define more Vehicles, so it gets something like this:

```
   //v 2.0
    public enum Vehicle
    {
        Truck,
        Mini,
        Superbike,
        WaterBike
    }

    public Vehicle getCar(){
        ...
        return Vehicle.XXX;
    }
```

Many other apps are using this library , so i don't want to break compatibility backwards.
 I need to migrate (just replace) the library from 1.0 to 2.0 in all the applications without breaking anything. Considering a new type will be returned in getCar() method, old code in the apps  will not understand that.

How do you propose to evolve the library? It`s a design question.

Answer (score 0):

Old code does not have to understand a new Enum type.

If old code checks enum type for Truck and gets WaterBike then it will not takes action on it just as if it got Mini.

Comment: Are u sure about that?